# Grep Values from a String in perl

Tags: perl

I have array that will have some values like this :

```
("test","test1","test3").
```

Now i have a string that will have values like this `"test","test4","test3","test5"`

I want to get the matching values from string that are in the array

```
@has = grep(m/$_/i,$strin) @array_list;
```

How can we do this please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
@has = grep { $string =~ m/$_/ } @array_list;
```

In general, this code block should return true for the elements, which you want to have grepped.

Comment: It should be `grep { $string =~m/$_/ }`, I'd say.

Comment: Depends on `$string` is and what the author had in mind. Or is there some particular reason you think it should be that way?

Comment: this is not working see my question i have updated that

Comment: Actually, no. You don't _need_ to pass `grep` a code block. As [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) makes clear, it accepts either a code block or an expression as its first parameter. But when you use a block, you omit the comma between the first and second parameters.

Comment: True! I've removed the lie from the answer.